# How can I "wrap" a capacitor plugin in React so that I can manage it centrally?

Tags: reactjs, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Today, Capacitor had a new release that replaced the [@capacitor-community/http](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http) plugin with a [CapacitorHttp](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http) plugin.

I'm using Ionic React for my app so all my code is in TypeScript/React.

I want to test out the new `CapacitorHttp` plugin, but I also want to make it easy to revert back to using the `http` plugin if things don't work out.

Throughout my app, I have a lot of import statements like `import { Http } from '@capacitor-community/http';`.  In React, is there a way to somehow wrap this import so that I can import `MyCustomHttp` everywhere, and then in `MyCustomHttp`, import `CapacitorHttp` or `http`?  This would simplify my code by putting the import in one place, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Create your own file and do `export { CapacitorHttp as Http } from '@capacitor/core';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Konrad, you can use the `{ A as B }` in a custom file.  Here is a code example for the Capacitor Push Notifications plugin:

**PluginPushNotifications.ts**

```
import {
  ActionPerformed,
  PushNotifications,
  Token,
} from '@capacitor/push-notifications';

export type { ActionPerformed as PluginActionPerformed };

export type { Token as PluginToken };

export { PushNotifications as PluginPushNotifactions };
```

To help myself with my IDE's autocomplete, I re-exported everything with a `Plugin` prefix.